# Differential Equation Problem finding the Value

Tags: calculus

$(y'''-y"-4y'+4y)=2x^2-4x-1+2x^2e^{2x}+5xe^{2x}+e^{2x}$

I've already get the complementary function $y_{c}$$=$ $C$$_1$$e^x$$+$ $C$$_2$$e^{2x}$$+$$C$$_3$$e^{-2x}$
Also y$_p$$=$$A+Bx+Cx^2+Dxe^{2x}+Ex^2e^{2x}+Fx^3e^{2x}$

What  is the value of A,B,C,D,E,F?

Comment: There's is a closed parenthesis which doesn't match an open one

Comment: Now its okay thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y_p=A+B x+C x^2+D e^{2 x} x+E e^{2 x} x^2+F e^{2 x} x^3$

$y'_p=B+2 C x+2 D e^{2 x} x+D e^{2 x}+2 E e^{2 x} x^2+2 E e^{2 x} x+2 F e^{2 x} x^3+3 F e^{2 x} x^2$

$y''_p=2 C+4 D e^{2 x} x+4 D e^{2 x}+4 E e^{2 x} x^2+8 E e^{2 x} x+2 E e^{2 x}+4 F e^{2 x} x^3+12 F e^{2 x} x^2+6 F e^{2 x} x$

$y^{(3)}=8 D e^{2 x} x+12 D e^{2 x}+8 E e^{2 x} x^2+24 E e^{2 x} x+12 E e^{2 x}+8 F e^{2 x} x^3+36 F e^{2 x} x^2+36 F e^{2 x} x+6 F e^{2 x}$

Plugging into $$y^{(3)}-y''-4 y'+4 y$$
Must be $$4 A-4 B-2 C+(4 B-8 C) x+4 C x^2+ e^{2x}\left(4 D+10 E+6 F+(8 E+30 F) x+12 F x^2\right))\equiv$$
$$\equiv 2 x^2-4 x-1+e^{2 x}\left(2 x^2+5 x+1\right) $$
$$
\begin{cases}
4 A-4 B-2 C=-1\\
4 B-8 C=-4\\
4C=2\\
4 D+10 E+6 F=1\\
8 E+30 F=5\\
12F=2\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$\left(A= 0,B= 0,C= \frac{1}{2},D= 0,F= \frac{1}{6}\right)$$
$$y_p=\frac{1}{6} e^{2 x} x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Comment: How did you get this

Comment: $4 C x^2+x (4 B-8 C)+(4 A-4B-2C)+ e^{2 x} \left(12 F x^2+30 F x+4D+6F\right)$

Comment: Can you show sir?

Comment: I substituted $y_p$ in the differential equation. See my edit. @Sherlot

Comment: Btw sir where is letter E

Comment: @Sherlot I messed up with $LaTeX$. Now it should be OK

Comment: Thankyouu sir my only problem is how to simplify when the values plugged in we are the same in getting the derivatives again tahnkyou sir

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $D^3 -D^2 - 4 D + 4 = (D - 1)(D - 2)(D + 2)$

Comment: Yeah i've already Get that that is complementary function

Comment: I want to know the value of A B C D E F i tried it but its so long maybe there's a shortcut

Comment: try plugging in

Comment: Plug in what? Value?